# Use cryto.generateKeyPair with jsonwebtoken

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

In node 10 there is a new method `generateKeyPair`, that I am using like this:

```
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync("rsa", {
  modulusLength: 4096,
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: "spki",
    format: "pem"
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: "pkcs8",
    format: "pem",
    cipher: "aes-256-cbc",
    passphrase: "top secret"
  }
});
```

I am now trying to create a jwt from `jsonwebtoken` using this privateKey:

```
function createJWT(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.sign(
      { id: id + "" },
      privateKey,
      { algorithm: "RS256", expiresIn: "2h" },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(token);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work:

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:83:26)
    at Object.sign (/Users/francoisbillioud/Documents/Tests/SimpleQL/node_modules/jwa/index.js:76:45)
    at jwsSign (/Users/francoisbillioud/Documents/Tests/SimpleQL/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
    at SignStream.sign (/Users/francoisbillioud/Documents/Tests/SimpleQL/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:58:21)
    at SignStream.<anonymous> (/Users/francoisbillioud/Documents/Tests/SimpleQL/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:46:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at DataStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at DataStream.<anonymous> (/Users/francoisbillioud/Documents/Tests/SimpleQL/node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js:32:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

You can have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4zr98zn884).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By providing a cipher and passphrase, the private key will be encrypted with PKCS#5 v2.0 password based encryption as per [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_keyobject_export_options). The `jsonwebtoken` module states the following:

> In case of a private key with passphrase an object { key, passphrase }
>   can be used (based on crypto documentation), in this case be sure you
>   pass the algorithm option.

If you really need to encrypt the private key, you'll need to save the passphrase used in the cryptographic generation of the private key and provide it in your `sign()` function.

```
let passphrase = 'top secret'

const { privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync("rsa", {
  modulusLength: 4096,
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: "spki",
    format: "pem"
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: "pkcs8",
    format: "pem",
    cipher: "aes-256-cbc",
    passphrase
  }
});

function createJWT(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.sign(
      { 
        id: id + "" 
      },
      {
        key: privateKey,
        passphrase
      },
      { 
        algorithm: "RS256", 
        expiresIn: "2h" 
      },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(token);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh! Ok, thank you so much! So if I got it right, I can either remove the `passphrase` property from `privateKeyEncoding`, or provide a `{key, passphrase}` object as private key to `jsonwebtoken`? I'll try that right away.

Comment: If you have no need within your system to encrypt the private key itself, you have to remove the `cipher` and `passphrase` fields in your `generateKeyPairSync()` function call. If you feel like you need, then yes, `{key, passphrase}` object as private key to `jsonwebtoken`

Comment: All right. Indeed I needed to remove also the `cipher` field. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent, glad I was able to help.

Comment: do web need to pass the same object for verification, like ```jwt.verify(token, { key, passphrase })``` ?